# Showing the OU a contact belongs to in GAL?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2007, contacts

We have recently imported about 1000 "external" contacts into our Exchange 2007 Server.

The external contacts were imported from a number of CSV files that had the contacts organised into categories. For example, CSV1 might have contained the "Hospitals" list, and CSV2 might have been the "Government Agencies" list.

During the import of each CSV Exchange was directed to put the contacts from that list into an OU in AD (e.g. ["My Company External Contacts", "Hospitals"] and ["My Company External Contacts", "Government Agencies"]).

This approach allows our users to selectively sync their smart phones for particular external contact lists that interest them in their role.

However, in the Global Address List the users are having trouble distinguishing which number they want because the OU name isn't visible anywhere.

Is there away to get the GAL to display the name of the OU a contact belongs to? Or a way to copy the OU name into a custom field and have that display in the GAL?

Answer (score 0):

The GAL dialog has a "more columns" option that presents a small subset of other account attinbutes.

[image]

You could choose one of those attributes to store the OU container name in.
The forum is not a script writing service, but it would be pretty easy to then use the Powershell *ADUser cmdLets

```
Get-ADUser -searchbase <stuff> | foreach {
    Set-ADUser -Replace <stuff>
}
```

to populate one of those columns with the name of the OU it resides in